# Car makes "chugging" sound when breaking

Tags: toyota, brakes, yaris

Have a 06 Yaris, replaced the rear break shoes and drums about a month ago now. Whenever I slow down with my breaks (only makes noise when I break) the left rear break makes a chugging sound. Did I put the brakes on too tight or what???

Comment: Welcome to the site. There is no way for us to know if you assembled them correctly, let alone if they are adjusted properly. You will need to go back in for a look and give us more information so we can try to answer your question.

Comment: Can you provide a sound recording?